# SQL: sub-query that returns rows containing "most popular" foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, subquery

schemas:

```
test_record
-----------------------------------------------
|test_id | type_id | patient_no | medical_lab | 
-----------------------------------------------

test_type

----------------------
|type_id | test_name |
----------------------

medical_lab

------------------------------
| lab_name | address | phone |
------------------------------
```

Note: type_id is a foreign key that references test_id

I need to find the most popular medical labs. The most popular medical lab is a lab that conducts more tests of any type than any other medical lab.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT      medical_lab
FROM        test_record, test_type
WHERE       medical_lab = lab_name
AND         test_record.type_id = test_type.type_id 
GROUP   BY  type_id
HAVING      COUNT(type_id) // not sure what to put here
```

As you can see I'm stuck on the COUNT part. I basically want it so that this query will only return any medical lab that has conducted more tests than other medical labs of the same type.

example:

```
lab example1 has conducted 10 tests of type 1
lab example2 has conducted 3 tests of type 1
lab example2 has conducted 2 tests of type 2
lab example3 has conducted 1 test of type 2
```

this query should then return:

```
lab example1 // because it has done 10 tests of type 1
lab example2 // because it has conducted 2 tests of type 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery will calculate the number of tests done for each test by each lab

The outer select will pick lab with maximum test counts for each test

```
SELECT T.lab_name, T.test_name, MAX(testcount)
FROM
(
    SELECT M.lab_name, TT.test_name, COUNT(TT.test_name) as testCount
    FROM medical_lab M
    JOIN test_record TR
    ON M.lab_name = TR.medical_lab
    JOIN test_type TT
    ON Tt.type_id = TR.type_id
    GROUP BY M.lab_name, TT.test_name
) T
GROUP BY T.lab_name, T.test_name
```